# Authlogic current_user_session and current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I have the following helper methods in the application_controller.rb for authlogic:

```
def current_user_session
  return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
  @current_user_session = UserSession.find
end

def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
end
```

I do not understand how the current_user_session method - specifically, how UserSession.find obtains the current user's session. I also do not understand what it is doing with find, where no argument is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't need to pass it an argument since it uses a [unique session ID](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/id.rb) whose functionality is [built into Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sessions). Check out the [authlogic documentation for the find method](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/persistence.rb#L13) for more information on it. It's not the same thing as an Active Record class, where `find` queries the database for a specific primary key.